# Convert list into an array using php. How?

Tags: php, arrays, string, list

I have a function called `listelements()`, which outputs text like `<li>text1</li><li>text2</li>`.

I have more than 500 elements. Now I want to convert it into an array.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Note: I'm using php

### Update:

The thing i want to achieve is alphabetical navigation. As of now my function displays links in list order. Instead of that i want to hold that in an array. Then i would like to filter them using characters.

```
$valid_characters = range( 'a' , 'z' );
$valid_numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);
```

When the user click "A" i would like to display only links start with A.
Hope this explanation helps you guys for better understanding my question

Comment: read this : http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

Comment: wat is the output array you are expecting?

Comment: What is the input into `listelemets()`? Use that, it is likely an array itself.

Comment: Do you want only text or with the `li` tag?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just modify the function to output an array in the first place instead of the html code?

Comment: A comment to my answer states the OP wants `listelemets()` **converted** to return an array, and that some list items contain links. OP please post 1) The source for `listelements()` 2) Details of any/all parameters passed to `listelements()` and 3) The  array structure you desire.

Comment: @Sirko Yes i think so. But it will be confuse me more. I just a php beginner

Comment: @user1091558: Still missing the input to the function, and the array structure you expect returned.

Comment: @Leigh Sorry, My net got disconnected. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$output = listelements();
$array = explode("<li>", $output);

//First element will be empty, so remove it
unset($array[0]);

// Now remove "</li>" at end of input
array_walk($array, create_function('&$val', '$val = str_replace("</li>", "", $val)'));

// $array should now contain your elements
```

Comment: In case there is something between 2 li-s, this does not work fine.

Comment: Sure, but OP specified the format as multiple concatations of `"<li>$element</li>"`, so no problem there.

Answer (score 2):

explode won't do the trick nicely for html tags (considering them as multiple delimiters).

if CPU time is not a concern, try using preg_match, example below:

```
<?PHP

$input='<li>text1</li><li>text2</li><LI><p>text3</p></lI><Li>text fou4r</li>';

preg_match_all('(<(li|Li|LI|lI)>(.*)</(li|Li|LI|lI)>)siU', $input, $output);

print_r($output[2]);
?>
```

output:

```
Array

    (

        [0] => text1
        [1] => text2
        [2] => <p>text3</p>
        [3] => text fou4r
    )
```

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: If your pattern is case insensitive, why are you matching all variations of case? And even then why would you do that instead of `[LlIi]`?

Comment: I think its better solution than iblue's above... Use regexp instead of explode and str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
$strarr=explode("<li>",$string); //Breaks every <li>
$i=(-1); //Makes -1 as array starts at 0
$arr=array(); //this will be your array
foreach($strarr as $expl){ //Go through all li's
$ai=explode("</li>",$expl);//Get between the li. If there is something between </li> and <li>, it won't return it as you don't need it
if($i!=(-1))$arr[$i]=$ai[0]; //First isn't valid
$i=$i+1; //add i plus one to make it a real array
}
```

Comment: This has syntax errors; explode() needs an assignment, and there's no "new" keywords for arrays

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I always forget that. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use simple_html_dom**
https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm

```
require_once(./simple_html_dom.php);
$html = "<ul class=''><li class=''>Swagger transforms unfreshmen into legends of confidence</li><li class=''>Red Zone collection</li><li class=''>Enhances awesomeness</li><li class=''>Continue your confidence with Swagger Anti-perspirant & Deodorant and Body Spray</li><li class=''>Old Spice Red Zone Swagger Scent Men’s Bar Soap</li></ul>";

$result = li_to_array($html);
var_dump($result ); 

    
function li_to_array($str)
{
    if (is_string($str) && !empty($str)) {
        $html = str_get_html($str);
        $results= array();
        $response_results = $html->find('li');
        foreach ($response_results as $response_result){
            array_push($results, $response_result->plaintext);
        } 
        unset($html); //release memory

        return  $results;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **"preg_match"**.

Here is more detail: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not